# How do I insert data into a Webmin MySQL Database using PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert data into a Webmin MySQL Database, but every time I hit submit on my form, It doesn't put the information in the MySQL database. I ran a test and it's running all the way to the INSERT part but it still didn't put anything in the DB. I can read from it just fine, but I can't write to it. I have all the permissions, but it still doesn't work. It also get all of the variables ($tblusername, $tblemail, $tblpassword). Here's my PHP (I'm using PDO.) Please help!

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        try {
        $tblusername = $_POST['Username'];
        $tblemail = $_POST['Email'];
        $tblpassword = $_POST['Password'];

        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mealplan", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT UserName FROM tblUsers");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $tblusername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
        die("Username already in use!");
        }else{
          $sql = "INSERT INTO `tblUsers` (`UserName`, `Email`, `UserPassword`) VALUES ($tblusername, $tblemail, $tblpassword)";
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->execute();
        }
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo "<style>.hidden { visibility: visible; } .shown { visibility: hidden; font-size: 0px }</style>";
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). But the error, here, is that you're missing quotes around values.

Comment: do you have code I can implement because i'm new to PHP.

Comment: thanks a lot! It works now! I will put that in soon!

Comment: I have another problem. It will put in information, but if there is something else in there, it wont put it in the database

Comment: Make a "SELECT" query first. If no result then "INSERT" else "UPDATE".